# Using xacro to automate inertial calculations sequence/float error

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-kinetic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS-Kinetic
I am trying to automatically calculate inertial values for a simulated robot. The purpose is to be able to change the dimensions and have the inertia automatically calculated. Here is my macro

```
  <xacro:macro name="cuboid_inertial" params="mass length width height">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia 
                ixx="${0.83*mass*(${width}+${height})}" 
                ixy="0.0" 
                ixz="0.0" 
                iyy="${0.83*mass*(${length}+${height})}" 
                iyz="0.0" 
                izz="${0.83*mass*(${width}+${length})}" />
    </inertial>
</xacro:macro>
```

I have xacro properties as follows.

```
  <xacro:property name="base_link_length" value="0.50"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_link_width" value="0.30"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_link_height" value="0.35"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_link_length_sqrd" value="${base_link_length}*${base_link_length}"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_link_width_sqrd" value="${base_link_width}*${base_link_width}"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_link_height_sqrd" value="${base_link_height}*${base_link_height}"/>
```

When I try to run the macro it comes up with an error. My link tags...

```
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_link_length} ${base_link_width} ${base_link_height}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="grey"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_link_length} ${base_link_width} ${base_link_height}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
        <xacro:cuboid_inertial mass="{base_link_mass}" length="{base_link_length_sqrd}" width="{base_link_width_sqrd}" height="{base_link_height_sqrd}"/>
  </link>
```

The error is
unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)
when evaluating expression '(.82)*${mass'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293281/using-xacro-to-automate-inertial-calculations-sequence/float-error/) by [Mrhinelander](https://answers.ros.org/users/35699/mrhinelander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-06-05**:
Somehow the error you posted doesn't seem to correspond to the code you posted in your macro. Your numbers are different and your parentheses and braces are different.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-06**:
This seems like a duplicate of #q293296. If it is, please close either this one, or #q293296, so we avoid split discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following for your macro works on my system:

```
  <xacro:macro name="cuboid_inertial" params="mass length width height">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia 
                ixx="${0.83*mass*(width+height)}" 
                ixy="0.0" 
                ixz="0.0" 
                iyy="${0.83*mass*(length+height)}" 
                iyz="0.0" 
                izz="${0.83*mass*(width+length)}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
```

I also changed the property block:

```
<xacro:property name="base_link_length" value="0.50"/>
<xacro:property name="base_link_width" value="0.30"/>
<xacro:property name="base_link_height" value="0.35"/>
<xacro:property name="base_link_length_sqrd" value="${base_link_length*base_link_length}"/>
<xacro:property name="base_link_width_sqrd" value="${base_link_width*base_link_width}"/>
<xacro:property name="base_link_height_sqrd" value="${base_link_height*base_link_height}"/>
```

Notice that I've changed the location of the `${}` sets in your calculations.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrhinelander](https://answers.ros.org/users/35699/mrhinelander/) on 2018-06-06**:
Thank you! Just as a followup, in xacro. When you use ${} is everything inbetween the brackets in the xacro namespace so all variables are essentially global variables? Sorry if that does not make sense.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-06-07**:
The `${}` is used for [math](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Math_expressions) expressions and for [substituting property values](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Property_and_Property_Blocks). For math expressions, anything inside the braces is evaluated with Python

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-06-07**:
By default all properties and macro arguments are locally scoped (properties only visible within the single xacro file and macro args only visible within the macro). However you can pass a `scope` attribute to expand these to the parent scope: http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Local_properties